# A question about SupA used in Lebesgue integration books

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

There is a classic Lemma about $sup A$ that says:

Let $A$ be any subset of the Real Numbers and let $s$ be an upper bound for $A$.
$s = supA$ iff for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $a \in A$ such that $s- \epsilon<a$. Similarly for $l=infA$ the inequality takes the form $a<l+\epsilon$.

In many books (e.g. Stein Real Analysis, p. 13), after define the outer measure of a set they use the above Lemma but  instead of $a<l+\epsilon$ they write $a\leq l+\epsilon$.

Is this Correct??? and if yes How can I prove it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try to prove that both characterizations are equivalent?

Comment: I was trying but  it seems to me they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $l$  be  such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $a\in A$ with $a \le l + \epsilon$.

Now, let $\tilde \epsilon > 0$. Then, for $\epsilon=\tilde\epsilon /2$ there exists some $a\in A$ with 
$$ a \le l + \tilde\epsilon /2 < l + \tilde\epsilon. $$

It is only important that $\epsilon$ is positive.

Note: You have forgotten to mention that $l$ should be a lower bound of $A$ :D

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. About the other direction?

Comment: @Studentmathever just write down the two definitions. After all $<$ implies $\le$.

Comment: @Studentmathever just write down the two definitions. After all $<$ implies $\le$.